# How to connect & program Powered Up train motor?

Tags: trains, powered-up

I'm new to LEGO and am trying to motorize my Hogwarts Express train. Per the LEGO site, I bought the 88011 Train Motor and the 88006 Move Hub. But I can't figure out how to use them. I connected the wire from the Train Motor to the C and D ports but get nothing.

I downloaded the Powered Up App (which I also don't understand) which was synced with the Move Hub so at least I know the Hub batteries were installed correctly. Within the app I created a project ("Train") but then what?  Are there instructions that explain the icons in the app and how to use them?

I also have a controller from a City Passenger Train (which does run) but I don't see how to use it with the 88011 Train Motor.  The controller seems to control ports A and B but ports A and B on the Move Hub look like red axles.

I've tried YouTube but the YouTube videos don't bother explaining these basics as if to say "If you have to ask, you're probably too dumb to use LEGOs."

So, can someone please help me get to first base by getting this train motor to do something? What do I plug the Train Motor cable into?  And then, how do I say "GO"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "City Passenger Train" do you mean 60197, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there instructions that explain the icons in the app and how to use them?

Yes - in LEGO Customer Service section. At the time of this writing:

- [LEGO® Powered Up programming blocks](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/help/Power_Functions/LEGO-Powered-Up-programming-blocks-kA06N000000g04eSAA) (web page)
- [LEGO® Powered Up programming blocks](https://www.lego.com/cdn/cs/service/assets/blt5e2546716d484ba8/PoweredUp-ProgrammingBlocks.pdf) (PDF file)

At the very least, you'll want to start the program...

[image: start program block]

...set power to the motor connected to port C (or D, as appropriate)...

[image: set power block]

...wait a few seconds...

[image: wait block]

...then end the program.

[image: end program block]

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is EXACTLY what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much, Ivan!  This is EXACTLY what I needed.

For the benefit of others, here is how I connected it.
I decided to attach the Motor Hub to the top of the Train Motor. But, before building up the Train Motor, I strongly advise attaching everything and trying it out.

Step 1: Put batteries in the Motor Hub.  If the light doesn't go on when you hit the green button then you probably have a problem with the batteries.

Step 2: Attach the cable from the Train Motor to either the C or D port of the Motor Hub.

Step 3: Download the LEGO Powered Up App.  With the app, create a new "project" for your train.  Then using bluetooth sync the app to the Motor Hub.  This part is tricky but when it's all synced and ready, there will be a green checkmark over the bluetooth symbol on app.

Step 4: Following the advice in Ivan's post above, create a simple program by dragging the pieces from the bottom of the app to the center section and connecting them.

- I recommend inserting a pause right after the "Go" (green arrow) to give you time to put your hands on both sides of the train to keep it from flying off.
- Then add the olive green "start motor" block (it has a lightning bolt.)
  This block has 2 important parameters. The left parameter sets the
  port.  Change this from A to C or D, depending on where you connected
  the Train Motor cable.  The second parameter specifies the speed and
  the direction.  A negative speed sends the train in reverse.

Step 5: The Train Motor replaces the "coal car".  I disassembled the "coal car" and used the parts (plus other spare parts) to build up the Train Motor such that I could attach the Motor Hub on top of the Train Motor.  The trickiest part of this is that the Motor Hub is much longer than the Train Motor so, in other to allow the new "motorized" car to attach to the other cars using the coupling plates, I needed to extend it in such a way that the coupling plates were at the same height as on the other cars.  This took a few hours of fiddling.

Step 6: There are a lot of other things you can do with that app.  For example, you can connect things to the red A and B ports and set your program so that they also spin while the train is running.